# Trigger que al hacer update a una tabla realice el update a otra diferente SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, trigger

Actualmente tengo una tabla llamada referencias, cada vez que se cambia el campo "Promoción" (valores S o N) debe automáticamente insertar un texto en el campo descripcion_3 de la tabla referencias_des_adi.

Aclaro que el enlace de ambas tablas es el campo código.

Tengo este trigger pero no saca error, ni tampoco almacena la información que estoy solicitando:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[UPD_Promocion] ON [dbo].[referencias]
AFTER INSERT
    ,UPDATE
AS
DECLARE @codigo AS VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @promocion AS CHAR(1)

SELECT @codigo = i.codigo
    ,@promocion = i.promocion
FROM inserted i
JOIN referencias_des_adi r
    ON i.codigo = r.codigo

IF @promocion = 'S'
BEGIN
    UPDATE referencias_des_adi
    SET descripcion_3 = 'PROMOCIÓN'
    WHERE codigo = @codigo
END

IF @promocion = 'N'
BEGIN
    UPDATE referencias_des_adi
    SET descripcion_3 = ''
    WHERE codigo = @codigo
END

RETURN
```

De antemano mil gracias por la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay, para comenzar, un error de concepto en tu trigger, y es que asumes que el trigger se disparará una vez por cada fila que se inserte/actualice, es decir, que la pseudo-tabla `inserted` siempre va a tener un único registro, pero esto no es correcto.

El ejemplo más sencillo es si se realiza una actualización masiva a la tabla, imagina la sentencia:

```
update UPD_Promicion set Promicion = 'S';
```

Si la tabla tiene un millón de filas en ese momento, la pseudo-tabla `inserted` en el trigger tendrá ese mismo millón de filas.

Por lo que mencionas, hay un segundo error:

> pero no saca error, ni tampoco almacena la información que estoy solicitando

Acá, lo que me temo, es que no siempre va a existir un registro para el `codigo` involucrado en la tabla `referencias_des_adi`, sin embargo, tu solo consideras la actualización de el o los registros existentes, y nunca la inserción en la tabla. Si cabe la posibilidad que al ejecutarse el trigger no exista información en dicha tabla, debes considerar la inserción de los datos. Si el flujo de la información es que siempre que se inserte en una tabla debe insertarse en la otra, puedes separar la lógica en dos triggers distintos, uno para el `after insert` y otro para el `after update`, que reflejen esa lógica.

Si quieres mantener todo en un único trigger, entonces debes cubrir ambos casos. Una forma de hacerlo es usando una [sentencia `merge`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql), que permite hacer un insert o un update según sea necesario.

Resolviendo ambos problemas en un solo paso, podrías tener algo como:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[UPD_Promocion] ON [dbo].[referencias]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
begin
  merge referencias_des_adi
  using (select codigo, case 
                          when promocion = 'S' then 'PROMOCIÓN'
                          else ''
                        end descripcion_3
           from inserted
        ) as origen
     on referencias_des_adi.codigo = origen.codigo
   when matched then
 update set descripcion_3 = origen.descripcion_3
   when not matched then
 insert (codigo, descripcion_3)
 values (origen.codigo, origen.descripcion_3)
;
end
go
```

Esta sentencia `merge` hará la inserción y la actualización según haga el caso, la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql) explica a detalle su funcionamiento.

Además, ahora tratamos a la tabla `inserted` como una fuente de datos que puede tener uno o muchos registros, con lo que funcionará de manera adecuada en todos los casos que se dispare.

Comment: De antemano mil gracias por tu respuesta, pero tengo la duda, este código me funcionaría para SQL 2008? Es que actualmente esta versión es la que tenemos en la compañía en que actualmente laboro.

Comment: Lo desconozco, no mencionaste esa versión en la pregunta, por lo que escribí una respuesta para lo que comunmente se usa hoy día, que es SQL 2017/2019. SQL 2008 ya no tiene soporte de Microsoft y ya ni la documentación oficial se encuentra en línea, por lo que no puedo confirmarlo. Es probable que funcione, así que  creo que te corresponde probarlo y, si no, pues ya te he explicado cuales son los problemas que tienes en el planteamiento, si lees con calma y entiendes la respuesta, puedes escribir tu mismo un trigger con `insert` y `update`, sin utilizar `merge`.

Comment: Basándose en fuentes no oficiales, `merge` [si está soportado en SQL-2008](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/the-merge-statement-in-sql-server-2008/)

Comment: Buenos días, realicé la prueba y no tiene problemas de compatibilidad, pero desafortunadamente no funciona.
De antemano mil gracias por la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Comment: Buenos días. "no funciona" es una descripción incompleta del problema. ¿Cómo lo estás comprobando? ¿Hay mensaje(s) de error? ¿cuáles son?

Comment: Buenas tardes, primero que nada agradecerte por tu pronta respuesta.
Lo segundo es, no hay mensaje de error, pero tampoco realiza el update en la tabla referencias_des_adi al modificar el campo "Promocion" de la tabla referencias.
El código que me pasaste si es compatible con mi versión de SQL Server.

Comment: Sugiero que le agregues una cláusula `output` al `merge`, como esta: `OUTPUT $action, inserted.*, deleted.*;`. Luego, que en el Management Studio ejecutes un insert en la tabla `referencias` y observes la salida que queda en la pestaña de resultados. ¿qué dice?. Luego haz un `update` en la tabla, ¿qué queda en la pestaña de resultados?